# EC2 SSH Connection Auto Closed

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, command-line-interface

Need some help here.

I am setting up an AWS EC2 instance with Ubuntu, trying to connect via SSH using public IP and public DNS but both automatically closed for some reason every time.

The security group setting allows access.

How to resolve this?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On **ubuntu** instances **username** should be "**ubuntu**" and on amazon instances it should be "**ec2-user**".

Comment: I've noticed that most of your answers start have a comment from you along the lines of "Please let me know if it not works else if it works please mark my answer as correct." on them - and then if you get any feedback from the OP you ask them to accept or to upvote your answer. See, e.g. [What to do with user asking for upvote and accept?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/297597/1364007) for why this should not be done.

Comment: @WaiHaLee Ok thanks, I have check the SO post which your shared and follow the same instruction in future for the same.